# still confused Routing and child Nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

i am working with nativescript 4+ angular framework. i had done login and register component. but right now i get trouble with main component.

the tree is like this

```
app
{
   main,
   login,
   register
}
```

then. main has `canActivate` the guard. if user don't login yet. user has to login first or create account.

the problem is main component that has many childs.

my mainRouting is like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './home/profile.component';
import { AddStoreComponent } from './home/add-store/add-store.component';
import { EditProfileComponent } from './home/edit-profile/edit-profile.component';
import { StoreComponent } from './store/store.component';
import { EditStoreProfileComponent } from './store/edit-store-profile/edit-store-profile.component';
import { GoodsComponent } from './store/goods/goods.component';
import { AddGoodsComponent } from './store/goods/add-goods/add-goods.component';
import { EditGoodsComponent } from './store/goods/edit-goods/edit-goods.component';
import { StaffComponent } from './store/staff/staff.component';
import { AddStaffComponent } from './store/staff/add-staff/add-staff.component';
import { EditStaffComponent } from './store/staff/edit-staff/edit-staff.component';
import { StoreProfileComponent } from './store/store-profile/store-profile.component';
import { TransactionComponent } from './store/transaction/transaction.component';
import { AddTransactionComponent } from './store/transaction/add-transaction/add-transaction.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/profile',
                pathMatch: 'prefix'
            },
            { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
            { path: 'edit-profile', component: EditProfileComponent },
            { path: 'add-store', component: AddStoreComponent },
            {
                path: 'store:id',
                component: StoreComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: '/store-profile',
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    { path: 'store-profile', component: StoreProfileComponent },
                    {
                        path: 'edit-store-profile',
                        component: EditStoreProfileComponent
                    },
                    { path: 'goods', component: GoodsComponent },
                    { path: 'edit-goods', component: EditGoodsComponent },
                    { path: 'add-goods', component: AddGoodsComponent },
                    { path: 'staff', component: StaffComponent },
                    { path: 'edit-staff', component: EditStaffComponent },
                    { path: 'add-staff', component: AddStaffComponent },
                    { path: 'transaction', component: TransactionComponent },
                    {
                        path: 'add-transaction',
                        component: AddTransactionComponent
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

is my mainRouting good or suck?

my target is when i go to `main component` is automatically go to `profile component`

but my code doest work.

i have tried change `path : 'profile' to path : ''`. it works. but i need to call `'/profile' route` and i want `route ''` to be my root for `route '/main'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your pattern work, you have to define a non-empty path on `MainComponent` meaning that all the subroutes show in the `MainComponent` layout. That is useful in case you have multiple layouts. But in your case you have only one layout, then you can simply put it in `AppComponent` and it allows you to get rid of the empty parent route that causes your problems

Comment: but i need to import `MainComponent` in MainComponentHtml has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for the childs

Comment: If your project has been created with Angular CLI, you should have `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` in your `app.module.ts`, then why you don't define your layout and `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your bootstrapped component `AppComponent` ?

Comment: i still new in angular. so i have to keep trying something new. @YoukouleleY

but. if i change the child route `path : 'profile'` to `path:''`. it works. so i think that if i redirect the route `''` to `/profile` it will work.

Comment: there is no point in having a `MainComponent` and overlapping routes, when `AppComponent`'s purpose is to hold your `MainComponent` logic

Comment: you still can try something new, I'm just telling you one clean solution (this is the purpose of questions in this site i guess)

Comment: Thanks for your solution sir. @YoukouleleY . And what condition should i use child component ? I am still not sure about dividing component to be parent and childs or just 1 component

Comment: @SulaimanTriarjo I'm not sure if I got what you meant, but If you're asking a use case for your implementation as is, the answer is: If you want to make your pattern work, you have to define a non-empty path on `MainComponent` meaning that all the subroutes show in the `MainComponent` layout. That is useful in case you have multiple layouts. But in your case you have only one layout, then you can simply put it in `AppComponent` and it allows you to get rid of the empty parent route that causes your problems